# Performance of Tizen Web Simulator

Tags: html, performance, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-web-simulator

I'm going to make a game for Samsung Tizen using HTML5/CSS. I don't have real device so the only way is to use simulator( web-simulator Ripple - extension for Chrome). As I checked it seems to be quite fast - much faster than Tizen system emulator.

So the question is: How will be look like performance after deploying on real device - comparing to simulator?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, performance on a real device is different.
To get Tizen Software Developer Phone (SDP) try to contact your local Samsung office.
Or there's RTL (Remote Test Lab) for trying your apps on real devices remotely. There are Android devices accessible only for now. Tizen SDPs will be shared later, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

For a web app it doesn't make much difference if you test on simulator or emulator but the point would be the browser support for certain HTML5 features. For quick prototyping and testing browser based extensions are much faster but the end product has to be verified in the emulator. I found the emulator is in nascent stage and it requires hello lot of improvement. It eats up memory and slower than a browser extension. Moreover some of the gestures like Swipe is hard with emulator.

Answer (score 0):

**The answer is**: You cannot tell how the performance will look like on a real device just by running your app on the Web Simulator. You should use a real device (preferably the  target device for you app) for any meaningful performance, stability measurements.

**And here is why:**

1. Web Simulator is running on Chrome/Chromium so it uses Chrome Webkit
   version (although Ripple works on all browser) the devices and the emulator use the
   [Web Runtime (WRT)](https://developer.tizen.org/help/topic/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/basics_tizen_programming/web_runtime.htm) engine a [modified Webkit especially for
   Tizen which has higher performance for HTML5 on some tests.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tizen#cite_ref-5)  [image]
   <sup>[[source of image | PDF | page 11]](http://download.tizen.org/misc/media/conference2012/tuesday/ballroom-a/2012-05-08_1515-1555-tizen_web_runtime.pdf)</sup>
2. Web Simulator, the Emulator and the device have different API implementations.
3. Web Simulator doesn't implement most of the functions it just simulates them. I've drawn here a simplified version of the Web Simulator just for you to make an idea:
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the performance on simulator or even on emulator will be different of that on the real device.

To test the app properly you will have to test it on real device.